# Div not centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#example').fadeIn('fast');">FadeIn!</a>

<div class="midbox" id="example" style="display:none;">
    Lorum ipsum<br>
    <br>
    [<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#example').fadeOut('fast');">Close</a>]
</div>
```

```
.midbox{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:35%;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

I've searched through many topics on Google and here on Stackoverflow, but i can't seem to find my answer.

I put the midbox classes just before the end of the body tag (`</body>`). Now i click on this link to fade the box in, but it isn't showing up in the middle, it shows up without the css i gave it and at the bottom of the page.

Why is it doing this? Can you guys help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/kRtUY/  Which browser you are using

Comment: Do you have a link to this page? It can be something with relative containers etc... Btw, giving something 50% top doesnt make it center vertically, you need to give it a negative margin of half the height to pull it back up.

besides that: are there more midboxes? because then they all need a unique id otherwise your jQuery screws it up... (Well jQuery does it right, you screwed it up :D)

Comment: also: 1) use jQuery to attach your onclick, 2) use e.preventDefault() and use # in the href instead of javascript: since it gives errors in browsers that has js turned off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
.midbox{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:-300px;     /* half of width */
    margin-top:-200px;     /* half of height */
    padding: 8px;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ayiyaw)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/QAhQw/), your script is working.
Note that your midbox element is positioned absolute, butabsolutely positioned elements are positioned **relative** to the first parent that has a position different than `static`.
This case is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/QAhQw/1/).
Please check if this is not your case.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code in the css

`body, html{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Put the styles in the head of the page:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    <!--Your styles here-->
   .midbox{
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     top:50%;
     left:35%;
     padding: 8px;
   }

</style>
</head>
```

or better create an external css file and link it to the html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/your.css">
```